# Spring boot common logging

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I'm very new to the spring boot..

I understood that Spring Boot uses Commons Logging for all internal logging.

```
logging.level.root=warn
logging.level.org.springframework.web=debug
logging.level.org.hibernate=error
```

after adding this into application.properties file, application logs all the output and exceptions in the console..

so I have a requirement to print the logs only when the system throws the error not for the success response..

Comment: You enabled debug logging, so ofcourse it will log everything.

Comment: You should check the log levels for the library you are using... from the top of my head, they are `FATAL`, `ERROR`, `WARN,` `INFO`, `DEBUG` and `TRACE`

Answer (score 0):

> so I have a requirement to print the logs only when the system throws the error not for the success response..

The implementation of this requirement IMO heavily depends on your system
From the word "response" I understand that you're working with some kind of controller (like in spring mvc). But the controller method is only an entry point to your backend.
What if the controller calls the service that logs something (message logA), then (after logging) it calls another service that again logs something (message logB) and then in turn calls, dao to call the datatbase?
If, say, DB threw an error, the logA and logB messages are already logged and you can't "take that back".

So, in general, you can log that there was an error by explicitly catching the exception in controller and logging the error, or using [Controller advice](https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc) to intercept and log the exceptions "globally".

When you reach the point where you log the message you can log it with severity, say, ERROR and the logging framework will log it as long as its configured to log messages of that level from that logger.